# MySql using AS to change field name in PHP

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following field idd. It is however screwing up my code as I have to rename everything from `array['id']` to `array['idd']`. Is there anyway to fix this? I tried the following!

```
select * from table where (idd as id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *,idd as id from table where id = 2
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1, column2, ..., idd AS id, columni, columni+1, ...
FROM yourTable
WHERE id=2
```